# Can private data be created between 2 peers in single organisation? Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to implement my composer bna in go chaincode. I want private data feature in the chaincode.
BNA structure:
1 asset
3 participant (Manufacturer, Seller, Consumer)
2 transaction

I successfully created the go chaincode as per above requirement but now I want price information of asset to be private between Manufacturer and Seller.

The documentation states that [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html)

> starting in v1.2, Fabric offers the ability to create private data collections, which allow a defined **subset of organizations** on a channel the ability to endorse, commit, or query private data without having to create a separate channel.

It mentioned **subset of organisations**
Here I stuck as how to achieve this and what changes will be require in chaincode? What are the possible ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturer, Seller, Consumer should be 3 organization in your business network.

Private data collection distributes based on private data collection policy definition [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data-arch.html). So the one who is allowed to persist the data is expressed using the Signature policy syntax. Four roles are supported: member, admin, client, and peer. [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/endorsement-policies.html)

So I think it means, you can create private data between member of 2 Orgs.

> It mentioned subset of organisations

This means that private data collection could be created between for example subset (Org1, Org2) in a set of (Org1, Org2, Org3) on the same channel.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please check this web link for more info: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html